# Linq to SQL Chunked Delete or Update Operation?

Tags: sql, linq, transactions

I have a lot of rows to delete in a table, and using ADO.NET I might
send a SqlCommand with this text:

```
 WHILE(1=1)  
BEGIN  
DELETE TOP(5000) FROM myTable WHERE myval=123  
 IF @@ROWCOUNT < 5000 BREAK  
END
```

I would wrap that in a transaction or 2 and could then delete in chunks so the DB could come up for air.

I would like to do the same thing but in C# using LINQ-to-SQL, is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no mass update or mass delete operations in Linq-to-SQL (and with 
developement suspended on L2S, it's unlikely there ever will be)

The best you could do is

```
db.myTable.DeleteOnSubmit(db.MyTable.Where(m=>m.myval ==123).Take(5000));
```

But I'm pretty sure that will generate a SELECT followed by 5000 DELETE statements.

Comment: That's not very nice, but I guess it is what it is. It smells like I'd need to get the total row count and do my own chunking in a C# loop and then do the delete in LinqtoSql.

Thanks.